# Split Collection to two list depend on criteria

Tags: java, comparative-review

Let's say I have a List contains numbers:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

and I would like to split this to two lists:

- odd numbers
- even numbers

So I can do this two ways:

**Solution 1:**

Create two methods:

```
List<Integer> filterOdd(List<Integer> numbers){
    List<Integer> result  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Integer n : numbers){
        if(n % 2 != 0){
            result.add(n);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

List<Integer> filterEven(List<Integer> numbers){
    List<Integer> result  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Integer n : numbers){
        if(n % 2 == 0){
            result.add(n);
        }
    }
    return result;
 }
```

and in the code I will call:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 });

List<Integer> oddNumbers = filterOdd(numbers);
List<Integer> evenNumbers = filterEven(numbers);
```

and do something with these lists.

Disadvantage:

I do two loops over one collection.

**Solution 2:**

Create one method:

```
public void filter(List<Integer> numbers, List<Integer> oddNumbers, List<Integer> evenNumbers){
    for(Integer n : numbers){
        if(n % 2 != 0){
            oddNumbers.add(n);
        }else{
            evenNumbers.add(n);
        }
    }
}
```

and in the code I will call:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 });
List<Integer> oddNumbers  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
filter(numbers, oddNumbers, evenNumbers);
```

Disadvantage:

I hear that assigning results for parameters is bad practice.

Which solution is better?

Comment: "Disadvantage: I hear that assign results for parameters is a bad practice." <-- where did you read that? If it is the most practical for you, just use it...

Comment: I think the first one is better. Not only because it is most reusable, but because the second one can be created also by making calls to the 2 methods of the first solution

Comment: Assigning to parameters is definitely an abomination. But it is not what the OP does here. So that principle, however true, just do not apply here. Calling a method on a parameter is not an assignment.

Answer (score 10):

As already mentioned in the other answers, in Java 8 you can use lambdas and the stream API to remove a lot of boilerplate.

Both your solutions can be converted to use streams.

Solution 1 - two methods:

```
public List<Integer> oddNumbers(List<Integer> numbers) {
    return numbers.stream().filter(n -> (n % 2) != 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public List<Integer> evenNumbers(List<Integer> numbers) {
    return numbers.stream().filter(n -> (n % 2) == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Solution 2 - as single method:

```
public void filter(List<Integer> numbers, List<Integer> oddNumbers, List<Integer> evenNumbers) {
    Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> partitions = numbers.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(n -> (n % 2) == 0));
    evenNumbers.addAll(partitions.get(true));
    oddNumbers.addAll(partitions.get(false));
}
```

Comment: For solution 1, you can even pass the predicate as a parameter, and then just one method will be enough.

Answer (score 9):

If you only need to split collection into 2 pieces by a certain criterion, then there's a built-in collector to achieve this:

```
 final List<Integer> numbers = asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
 final Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> lists = numbers.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(n -> n % 2 == 0));
 System.out.println(lists.get(true));
 System.out.println(lists.get(false));
```

This will print:

```
  [2, 4]
  [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Indeed the solution I would go with. Also, in case of more than two options (so not a Boolean), there's also various `groupingBy` functions.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution which replicates Guava's `Predicate` interface. Since this interface is really easy, here is how it is done:

```
public interface Predicate<T>
{
    // returns true if input obeys the predicate
    boolean apply(T input);
}
```

Given this interface, implement it for your types; and then do a method like this:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> filteredLists(final List<T> list,
    final List<Predicate<T>> predicates)
{
    final int size = predicates.size();
    final List<List<T>> ret = new ArrayList<List<T>>(size);

    // Fill ret with initial lists
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        ret.add(new ArrayList<T>());

    // Now walk the predicates and add to the necessary lists

    for (final T element: list)
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (predicates.get(i).apply(element))
                ret.get(i).add(element);

    // Done! Return...
    return ret;
}
```

Now, if you had a utility class, say `MyPredicates`, with two methods `even()` and `odd()`, you could write:

```
final List<List<Integer>> filtered = filteredList(inputList,
    Arrays.asList(MyPredicates.even(), MyPredicates.odd()));
```

The "drawback" here is that it is up to the caller to remind what predicates where in what order in the calling lists, of course.

As to your `MyPredicates` hypothetical class:

```
public static final class MyPredicates
{
    // No instansiation
    private MyPredicates()
    {
    }

    public static Predicate<Integer> even()
    {
        return new Predicate<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(final Integer input)
            {
                return input.intValue() % 2 == 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Predicate<Integer> odd()
    {
        return new Predicate<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(final Integer input)
            {
                return input.intValue() % 2 == 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Go for two methods :

- the methods will lead to code that is more readable
- the signatures make more sense, and you don't need to use parameters as return values
- while this is probably slightly slower, we should remember that ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil" (Knuth)](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth); unless you can show that having two loops is a performance bottle neck in your code : don't optimize.
- this will be easier to refactor to using the Predicate approach that @fge suggests. Even though at this point that would, in my opinion, be overkill. Nevertheless, a valid option once lambdas are available in 8.

Comment: In fact, Java 8 _will_ have `Predicate`... They have salvaged quite a few interfaces from Guava for that matter. Hurray!